# Changing app.config from another application

Tags: c#, database-connection, app-config

I made an application that is able to change its app.config (the connection string part). I tried several solutions and this proved to be the easiest way to solve one of my problems. This is the code I use:

```
ConnectionStringSettings postavke = new ConnectionStringSettings("Kontrolor.Properties.Settings.KontrolorConnectionString", constring);
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Clear();
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(postavke);   

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.SectionName);
```

This code is placed inside a button_click method, and when I click that button and restart the application the changes are visible.
My question is this - is there a way to do it from another (independent) application that would enable the user to create the connection string by entering the required values into a textBox or selecting it from comboBox (he needs only to enter the IP of the server and the name of the database). By doing that, the first application would be preprepared and there would be no need to restart it to apply changes.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: are you controlling both applications ?

Comment: Yes. The idea is this - since this application will be used by 2 types of users (administrators and workers) I want to enable administrators to change application settings, but workers don't even need to be aware that this functionality exists. My alternative is to make a MenuStrip item that is (in)visible depending on credentials that user logs in with, but the first approach seems more elegant to me (there is no restarting application to apply the changes, it is set on startup and ready to be worked on)

Comment: if these applications running on the same machine you can send custom windows message, or better use WCF, here is the example for List-Based Publish-Subscribe : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx

Comment: They are on the same machine, and completely independent of other instances on other computers (except for the database(s), but that is not my concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both applications are on same machine you can use simple windows messaging, register windows message in both applications and sender post message to receiver, here is the example code:

Sender :

```
  public partial class FormSender : Form
  {
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

    private static readonly int WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION");

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

    public FormSender()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNotify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      NotifyOtherApp();
    }

    private void NotifyOtherApp()
    {
      List<Process> procs = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
      Process receiverProc = procs.Find(pp => pp.ProcessName == "Receiver" || pp.ProcessName == "Receiver.vshost");  
      if (receiverProc != null)
        PostMessage((IntPtr)receiverProc.MainWindowHandle, WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0));
    }
  }
```

Receiver :

```
 public partial class FormReceiver : Form
  {
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

    private static readonly int WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION");

    public FormReceiver()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      if (m.Msg == WM_REFRESH_CONFIGURATION)
      {
        lblMessageReceived.Text = "Refresh message recevied : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
      }
    }
  }
```

btw. note that I am checking for process name "Receiver.vshost" so that it can work when started in VS debugger